# Retrieving transaction referene with Omnipay, when issuers calls the website

Tags: php, omnipay

I cannot seem to find out how to retrieve the transaction reference.

Based on the gateway and the callback url that is called, is this possible?

```
$purchaseResponse = $gateway->completePurchase()->send();
if($purchaseResponse->isSuccessful())
{
     //please give me the transaction id!
```

(of course I can check it myself using the $_GET parameters, however, that does away with the 'universal' payment provider part.)

Comment: Which gateway are you using?

Comment: I am using Targetpay_Ideal, and later want to use Paypal and others.

Comment: Omnipay's base Response class has a `getTransactionReference()` function, however it hasn't been implemented for this gateway yet. I've added it to my todo list.